# Why can I not select both input elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to set a value to input element(s) that match the ID.

But the jQuery.each is picking up only the first/one input element.

I'm trying to perform a ajax post and i need both these ID to have the same value.

HTML

```
@Html.HiddenFor(u => u.TransID)   
//<input id="TransID" name="TransID" type="hidden" value="0">

@Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.TransID, Model.TransModes)
//<input id="TransID" name="TransID" value="0">
```

Script

```
$("#TransID").each(function () {
    $(this).val("2")
    alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An `id` must be unique in HTML. If you want to name several elements the same then use `class` instead.

```
<input class="TransID" name="TransID1" type="hidden" value="0">

<input class="TransID" name="TransID2" value="0">
```

Script

```
$(".TransID").each(function () {
    $(this).val("2")
    alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

Comment: You type too fast, man :P

Comment: Your names also need to be unique otherwise you are going to override one of them when the form is submitted.

Comment: If the alert is just for debugging `$(".TransID").val("2");` is enough.

Comment: @prodigitalson, [that is actually incorrect](http://zzzzbov.com/blag/querystring-hell). If you're submitting multiple fields with the same key the query string (or form encoding) will have the key listed multiple times (e.x. `?foo=bar&foo=baz`). A correct query string parser will be able to get all the values correctly.

Comment: @MightyPork ... yeah, but unfortunately I always produce too many typos ... :-/ and -->prodititalson: of course, the names must be unique otherwise you will not be able to get anything sensible on the receiving end!

Comment: @prodigitalson, i should also mention that duplicate keys *must* be supported to handle `<select multiple>` elements.

Comment: Thanks for the hack. As much as i hate doing this i needed it.